# Add Y values as labels on a line chart, for some data points

Tags: javascript, charts, vega

I have a line chart, quite basic (see below for a simplified example that works on the Vega Editor).  Basically, it draws lines, the X axis is successive dates, the Y axis is some numerical values.

I am trying to add labels for some of the data points on the line, with the value of Y at that point.  Only for some of the data points, because some charts can be for over a year, so there can be hundreds of days (X values).

This is by the way how labels are put on the X axis automatically by Vega.  If there are too many X values, it does not display every day, it says e.g. "Jan 1", then "Jan 8", then "Jan 15", etc. (nice one!)

Just for reference, with C3 (a charting library for D3), I used the following to draw one label out of every 7 data point:

```
data: {
  json: data.data,
  type: 'spline',
  labels: {
    format: function(v, id, i, j) {
      if ( i % 7 === 3 ) {
        return d3.format('.2f')(v);
      }
    }
    ...
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start.  I did not find any such example, and could not find anything related in the documentation.

Just for reference, here is an example chart to which I'd like to add these labels:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 250,
    "autosize": {
        "type":   "fit",
        "resize": true
    },
    "data": [{
        "name": "table",
        "format": {
            "parse": {
                "date":  "date",
                "value": "number"
            }
        },
        "values": [
            { "date": "2017-09-01", "value": "12.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-01", "value": "4.34",  "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-02", "value": "13.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-02", "value": "13.34", "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-03", "value": "4.34",  "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-03", "value": "15.34", "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-04", "value": "15.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-04", "value": "5.34",  "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-05", "value": "16.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-05", "value": "6.34",  "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-06", "value": "17.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-06", "value": "17.34", "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-07", "value": "18.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-07", "value": "8.34",  "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-08", "value": "18.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-08", "value": "14.34", "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-09", "value": "9.34",  "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-09", "value": "14.34", "what": "two" },
            { "date": "2017-09-10", "value": "20.34", "what": "one" },
            { "date": "2017-09-10", "value": "4.34",  "what": "two" }
        ]
    }],
    "scales": [{
        "name": "x",
        "type": "utc",
        "range": "width",
        "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "date"}
    }, {
        "name": "y",
        "type": "linear",
        "range": "height",
        "nice": true,
        "zero": true,
        "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "value"}
    }, {
        "name": "color",
        "type": "ordinal",
        "range": "category",
        "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "what"}
    }],
    "axes": [{
        "orient": "bottom",
        "scale": "x",
        "encode": {
            "labels": {
                "interactive": true,
                "update": {
                    "fill":     {"value": "steelblue"},
                    "angle":    {"value": 50},
                    "fontSize": {"value": 14},
                    "align":    {"value": "left"},
                    "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
                    "dx":       {"value": 3}
                },
                "hover": {
                    "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
                }}}
    }, {
        "orient": "left",
        "scale": "y"
    }],
    "marks": [{
        "type": "group",
        "from": {
            "facet": {
                "name": "series",
                "data": "table",
                "groupby": "what"
            }
        },
        "marks": [{
            "type": "line",
            "from": {"data": "series"},
            "encode": {
                "enter": {
                    "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "date"},
                    "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "value"},
                    "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "what"},
                    "strokeWidth": {"value": 2}
                },
                "update": {
                    "interpolate": {"value": "monotone"},
                    "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
                },
                "hover": {
                    "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vega has a property called tickCount that can be added to your axes definitions. Adding this to your y-axis must solve your case:

```
{
    "orient": "left",
    "scale": "y",
    "tickCount": 4
}
```

You could use a signal as well if it should be dynamic.

The feature is even more powerful than illustrated. Go check out the docs for other options in below link:
https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/axes/